# Selenium Click() method in C# is not returning - Chrome

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a Selenium app with Google Chrome that tries to click on a Print button, but I'm getting an exception when trying to click on the link as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:printDoc()">Print</a>
```

The application is clicking on the link in this way:

```
    var printOption = browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='printLink']/div[1]/a"));
    printOption.Click();
```

The following error is being thrown in the last instruction:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:65480/session/db0e763311af8fdd4f0ca06d79365d85/element timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
```

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect to happen after the link is clicked? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I'm expecting a pop up. It opens the popup with the print preview window, it should load an iframe but from the application is not working, when I browse the page manually (by myself) it works successfully.

Comment: chrome, driver (selenium), Windows versions?

Comment: The error suggests the problem is in finding the element, not clicking it. Are you absolutely sure that is a working xpath?

Comment: @Parker Beck I'm completely sure,  because I also tested finding the element first, writing the element in a log and clicking after and the error is being thrown when the click function is called.

Comment: What's the next line of code? The click shouldn't be causing an error. Did you make sure to switch to the iframe before trying to find an element there?